# one transaction with several actions

Tags: solidity

I am wondering if the following code will produce the transaction with two actions:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.1
import "https://github.com/bla-bla-bla/contractA.sol";
import "https://github.com/bla-bla-bla/contractB.sol";

contract contractC {

  constructor() {
    contarct_a = contractA(contractA_address);
    contarct_b = contractB(contractB_address);
  }

  function foo(
     // interaction with contractA
     param1
     param2
     param3

     // interaction with contractB
     param4
     param5
     param6
  )
  contract_a.function1{ value: msg.value }(param1, param2, param3);
  contract_b.function2{ value: msg.value }(param4, param5, param6);
}
```

Comment: just imagine that all the contracts in in Ethereum are DLL librarries with functions you can call. The possibilities are endless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can interact with multiple contracts in a function call. Some call these sub-calls *Internal transactions*. Internal transactions may also result in more internal transactions, as long as the original caller provides enough gas to process all of it.

Your pseudocode looks ok otherwise, but you can't give the same *msg.value* to two contract calls because the first one would already use (send) all of the value.

Comment: thanks! so the ```fucntion2``` should be without ```{ value: msg.value }```?

Comment: `msg.value` always contains the amount of Ether sent with the transaction - there is no such thing as `msg1.value`. Usually you don't even want to send any Ether with your internal transactions, so you could just remove that part. Or if you want to send half to both, you can send `msg.value / 2`

Comment: yeah i edited the comment right after i sent it, thanks!